# JQuery fancybox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm students studying web design in Korea. 
I have a question. I'm using fancybox on my personal project. 
It's awesome!! However, I have a problem..

The homepage is simply constructed with like that

Contents
Fancybox image slide1
Contents
Fancybox image silde2

The important thing is slide1 and slide2 is not related. 
However, when I click small image of slide1, fancybox shows all of images including slide1 and slide2 images. 
I want to show only slide1 images in 'Fancybox image slide1'.

Please help me!! 
I attaching brief HTML source. Thank you!

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>

<body>
   contents<br>
   <div class="fancybox_image_slide1">
   <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="1_b.jpg"><img src="1_s.jpg"/></a>
   <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="2_b.jpg" ><img src="2_s.jpg"/></a>
</div>
contents<br>   
<div class="fancybox_image_slide2" >
   <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="3_b.jpg"><img src="3_s.jpg" /></a>
   <a class="fancybox" rel="group" href="4_b.jpg" ><img src="4_s.jpg"/></a>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It's because you're using the same `rel="group"` for every image. Change your first group to "group1" and second to "group2" and I think that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fancy box uses the rel attribute to handle grouping. Make sure that each group has matching values for the rel attribute.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
</script>

<body>
contents<br>
<div class="fancybox_image_slide1">
   <a class="fancybox" rel="slide1" href="1_b.jpg"><img src="1_s.jpg"/></a>
   <a class="fancybox" rel="slide1" href="2_b.jpg" ><img src="2_s.jpg"/></a>
</div>
contents<br>   
<div class="fancybox_image_slide2" >
   <a class="fancybox" rel="slide2" href="3_b.jpg"><img src="3_s.jpg" /></a>
   <a class="fancybox" rel="slide2" href="4_b.jpg" ><img src="4_s.jpg"/></a>
</div>
</body>
```